# Error installing CodeDeploy Agent on AWS EC2

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rpm, aws-code-deploy

When installing the CodeDeploy Agent on my newly created EC2 instance (Ubuntu 14.04), I ran into an error with `rpm` as I was following the steps on the [Install or Reinstall the AWS CodeDeploy Agent](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/how-to-run-agent-install.html) guide.

**Commands:**

```
wget https://aws-codedeploy-us-west-2.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/install

chmod +x ./install

sudo ./install auto
```

**Error:**

```
sudo: unable to resolve host ip-10-0-88-56
I, [2016-08-12T01:22:00.600236 #30533]  INFO -- : Starting Ruby version check.
I, [2016-08-12T01:22:00.600470 #30533]  INFO -- : Starting update check.
I, [2016-08-12T01:22:00.600565 #30533]  INFO -- : Checking AWS_REGION environment variable for region information...
I, [2016-08-12T01:22:00.600645 #30533]  INFO -- : Checking EC2 metadata service for region information...
I, [2016-08-12T01:22:00.627237 #30533]  INFO -- : Downloading version file from bucket aws-codedeploy-us-west-2 and key latest/VERSION...
I, [2016-08-12T01:22:00.666351 #30533]  INFO -- : Downloading version file from bucket aws-codedeploy-us-west-2 and key latest/VERSION...
I, [2016-08-12T01:22:00.695690 #30533]  INFO -- : Downloading package from bucket aws-codedeploy-us-west-2 and key releases/codedeploy-agent-1.0-1.1011.noarch.rpm...
I, [2016-08-12T01:22:00.756074 #30533]  INFO -- : Executing `/usr/bin/yum -y localinstall /tmp/codedeploy-agent-1.0-1.1011.noarch.tmp-20160812-30533-1j5n6zs.rpm`...
Setting up Local Package Process
Examining /tmp/codedeploy-agent-1.0-1.1011.noarch.tmp-20160812-30533-1j5n6zs.rpm: codedeploy-agent-1.0-1.1011.noarch
Marking /tmp/codedeploy-agent-1.0-1.1011.noarch.tmp-20160812-30533-1j5n6zs.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package codedeploy-agent.noarch 0:1.0-1.1011 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: codedeploy-agent-1.0-1.1011.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: codedeploy-agent-1.0-1.1011.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: codedeploy-agent-1.0-1.1011.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: codedeploy-agent-1.0-1.1011.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: codedeploy-agent-1.0-1.1011.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: /bin/sh for package: codedeploy-agent-1.0-1.1011.noarch
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: codedeploy-agent-1.0-1.1011.noarch (/codedeploy-agent-1.0-1.1011.noarch.tmp-20160812-30533-1j5n6zs)
           Requires: /bin/sh
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
E, [2016-08-12T01:22:00.847217 #30533] ERROR -- : Error installing /tmp/codedeploy-agent-1.0-1.1011.noarch.tmp-20160812-30533-1j5n6zs.rpm.
```

I did verify that:

- `/bin/sh` does exist
- Ruby 2.3.0 was installed via RVM

I am new to DevOps so not really sure where to go from here. Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 8):

Did you try with `sudo ./install deb`? It forces to use the Debian based installation process.

If it doesn't work, retry after installing gdebi with `sudo apt-get install gdebi`.

Comment: Thank you! sudo apt-get install gdebi heal env for me and sude ./install deb now works!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the main problem is the host name error:

```
sudo: unable to resolve host ip-10-0-88-56
```

I have had this issue; it appears to be some type of initialization error. I tried again with a new AMI launch, and it resolved itself.

Just to isolate the issue, try this:

```
echo "127.0.0.1 $(hostname)" >> /etc/hosts
```

Then retry the setup script.

For reference, I use the same exact steps to install CodeDeploy on Ubuntu 14.04; the steps are correct.

```
wget https://aws-codedeploy-${EC2_REGION}.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/install
chmod +x ./install
sudo ./install auto
sudo service codedeploy-agent status
```